# Bootstrap form grid layout has annoying vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The image says it all, but in case it doesn't: I am using Bootstrap 5 and creating a form with a grid layout. One label has multiple lines of text and it moves that item out of line with the others that are horizontally adjacent to it.

Offending HTML:

```html
<!-- Include Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <form action="/" method="POST" novalidate class="row g-3 validated-form">
            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <label for="address-line-1" class="form-label">Address Line 1</label>
                <input type="text" id="address-line-1" class="form-control" name="addressLine1" autocomplete="address-line1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <label for="address-line-2" class="form-label">Address Line 2</label>
                <input type="text" id="address-line-2" class="form-control" name="addressLine2" autocomplete="address-line2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" name="city" autocomplete="address-level2" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="region" class="form-label">Province/State</label>
                <input type="text" id="region" class="form-control" name="region" autocomplete="address-level1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                <label for="postcode" class="form-label">Postal Code/ZIP</label>
                <input type="text" id="postcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" autocomplete="postal-code" required>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to have these items align sensibly? I have tried using "d-flex align-items-end" to align each label/input combo at the bottom of their grid section but they unstack and I lose all the default form styling. Would really appreciate any suggestions, either in aligning things to the bottom or in a workaround.

[Badly aligned items.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN1TI.png)

Comment: You need to show us the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apologies @ahaworth, code is now included

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos your answer is just what I was looking for, thank you. I can't upvote it (no reputation)

Comment: You may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. Here you can find more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `align-items-end` class to the `form` element:

```html
<form action="/" method="POST" novalidate class="row g-3 validated-form align-items-end">
```

will give you this result:

[image: Form]

`align-items-end` is a flexbox utility class:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#align-items

The `form` has `display: flex;` because of the `row` class.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- Include Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <form action="/" method="POST" novalidate class="row g-3 validated-form">
            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <label for="address-line-1" class="form-label">Address Line 1</label>
                <input type="text" id="address-line-1" class="form-control" name="addressLine1" autocomplete="address-line1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <label for="address-line-2" class="form-label">Address Line 2</label>
                <input type="text" id="address-line-2" class="form-control" name="addressLine2" autocomplete="address-line2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" name="city" autocomplete="address-level2" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="region" class="form-label">Province/State</label>
                <input type="text" id="region" class="form-control" name="region" autocomplete="address-level1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                <label for="postcode" class="form-label">Postal Code/ZIP</label>
                <input type="text" id="postcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" autocomplete="postal-code" required>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- Include Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <form action="/" method="POST" novalidate class="row g-3 validated-form">
            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <label for="address-line-1" class="form-label">Address Line 1</label>
                <input type="text" id="address-line-1" class="form-control" name="addressLine1" autocomplete="address-line1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                <label for="address-line-2" class="form-label">Address Line 2</label>
                <input type="text" id="address-line-2" class="form-control" name="addressLine2" autocomplete="address-line2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
                <input type="text" id="city" class="form-control" name="city" autocomplete="address-level2" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="region" class="form-label">Province/State</label>
                <input type="text" id="region" class="form-control" name="region" autocomplete="address-level1" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="postcode" class="form-label">Postal Code/ZIP</label>
                <input type="text" id="postcode" class="form-control" name="postcode" autocomplete="postal-code" required>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You also have two code snippets, which one is supposed to be the answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).